# How to use wp-post editor in plugin

Tags: wordpress, editor

I want to use the post editor of wordpress in one of the plugins I'm developing. How am I supposed to add the editor to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Atlast I figured out a way to add the tiny-mce editor on my plugin.

You have to add a few script(s) and the post editor of wordpress will be available for you.

This is the code to use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-color' );
wp_enqueue_script('utils');
if (function_exists('add_thickbox')) add_thickbox();
wp_print_scripts('media-upload');
if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) wp_tiny_mce();
wp_admin_css();
wp_print_scripts('editor');
do_action("admin_print_styles-post-php");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
```

It's enough to add the tiny mce editor on your plugin.

Now the following line is necessary to display the editor:

Comment: <div>
<?php    the_editor(stripslashes($devOptions['purpose_content']),'purpose_content','purpose_content', true); 
?>
</div>

This is necessary for the editor to be displayed